# Trying to create API using flask for object detection YOLOV4. It is throwing some tensorflow error

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo

I am learning deep learning and practicing object detection using `YOLO`. Recently, I modified some code and successfully detect humans only using `YOLOV4 tensorflow GPU` from the code available in https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite. Now, I am trying to implement client-server architecture using `flask` and encountered an amazing problem.

First of all, I noticed that, the

```
app.run(main_func)
```

runs twice whenever I start the program. And later, it always got stuck in

```
pred_bbox = infer(batch_data)
```

which throws error like this:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:  
Error while reading resource variable batch_normalization_95/gamma_57417 from Container: localhost. 
This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. 
Not found: Resource localhost/batch_normalization_95/gamma_57417/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/functional_1/batch_normalization_95/ReadVariableOp}}]] 
[Op:__inference_signature_wrapper_5589]
```

Function call stack:

```
signature_wrapper
```

This error started occurring after I divided the program into two functions. I divided the program into two functions because I do not want to load the model every time, I hit the API and waste time, because it takes about 10-15 seconds to load.

My code snippet is here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
from absl import app, flags, logging
from absl.flags import FLAGS
import core.utils as utils
from core.yolov4 import filter_boxes
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from PIL import Image
import os
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
from helping_functions import get_centroids, get_human_box_detection, get_points_from_box
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify, send_from_directory, abort

flags.DEFINE_string('framework', 'tf', '(tf, tflite, trt')
flags.DEFINE_string('weights', './checkpoints/yolov4-416',
                    'path to weights file')
flags.DEFINE_integer('size', 416, 'resize images to')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('tiny', False, 'yolo or yolo-tiny')
flags.DEFINE_string('model', 'yolov4', 'yolov3 or yolov4')
flags.DEFINE_string('image', './data/kite.jpg', 'path to input image')
flags.DEFINE_string('output', 'result.png', 'path to output image')
flags.DEFINE_float('iou', 0.45, 'iou threshold')
flags.DEFINE_float('score', 0.25, 'score threshold')


infer = ""
input_size = 0
# Initialize Flask application
flask_app = Flask(__name__)

# API that returns JSON with classes found in images
@flask_app.route('/detection', methods=['POST'])
def human_detect():
    # flask_app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0', port=5000)
    while True:
        image = request.files["images"]
        image_path = image.filename
        image.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_path))
        # image_path = FLAGS.image
        if image_path != "":
            original_image = cv2.imread(f"./{image_path}")
            # print(original_image)
            original_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

            image_data = cv2.resize(original_image, (input_size, input_size))
            image_data = image_data / 255.
            image_data = image_data[np.newaxis, ...].astype(np.float32)
            batch_data = tf.constant(image_data)
            print("infer")
            print(infer)
            print()
            pred_bbox = infer(batch_data)
            print("pred_box")
            print(pred_bbox)
            print()
            for key, value in pred_bbox.items():
                boxes = value[:, :, 0:4]
                pred_conf = value[:, :, 4:]

            boxes, scores, classes, valid_detections = tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression(
                boxes=tf.reshape(boxes, (tf.shape(boxes)[0], -1, 1, 4)),
                scores=tf.reshape(
                    pred_conf, (tf.shape(pred_conf)[0], -1, tf.shape(pred_conf)[-1])),
                max_output_size_per_class=50,
                max_total_size=50,
                iou_threshold=FLAGS.iou,
                score_threshold=FLAGS.score
            )
            final_boxes = boxes.numpy()
            final_scores = scores.numpy()
            final_classes = classes.numpy()
            array_boxes_detected = []
            if len(boxes)>0:
                array_boxes_detected = get_human_box_detection(final_boxes,final_scores[0].tolist(),final_classes[0].tolist(),original_image.shape[0],original_image.shape[1])
            try:
                return jsonify({"response":array_boxes_detected}), 200
            except FileNotFoundError:
                abort(404)
        else:
            print("Waiting for imagepath")
            time.sleep(10)

def main_func(_argv):
    print()
    print("Running main function.")
    print()
    global infer
    global input_size
    if infer == "":
        config = ConfigProto()
        config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
        STRIDES, ANCHORS, NUM_CLASS, XYSCALE = utils.load_config(FLAGS)
        # image_path = FLAGS.image
        saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(FLAGS.weights, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
        infer = saved_model_loaded.signatures['serving_default']
    input_size = FLAGS.size
    # human_detect(infer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(main_func)
    except SystemExit:
        pass
    # app.run(main_func)
    flask_app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

This is before I modified the code by adding flask and dividing the code into two functions:

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
from absl import app, flags, logging
from absl.flags import FLAGS
import core.utils as utils
from core.yolov4 import filter_boxes
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
from helping_functions import get_centroids, get_human_box_detection, get_points_from_box

flags.DEFINE_string('framework', 'tf', '(tf, tflite, trt')
flags.DEFINE_string('weights', './checkpoints/yolov4-416',
                    'path to weights file')
flags.DEFINE_integer('size', 416, 'resize images to')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('tiny', False, 'yolo or yolo-tiny')
flags.DEFINE_string('model', 'yolov4', 'yolov3 or yolov4')
flags.DEFINE_string('image', './data/kite.jpg', 'path to input image')
flags.DEFINE_string('output', 'result.png', 'path to output image')
flags.DEFINE_float('iou', 0.45, 'iou threshold')
flags.DEFINE_float('score', 0.25, 'score threshold')

def main(_argv):
    config = ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
    STRIDES, ANCHORS, NUM_CLASS, XYSCALE = utils.load_config(FLAGS)
    input_size = FLAGS.size
    image_path = FLAGS.image

    original_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    original_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # image_data = utils.image_preprocess(np.copy(original_image), [input_size, input_size])
    image_data = cv2.resize(original_image, (input_size, input_size))
    image_data = image_data / 255.
    # image_data = image_data[np.newaxis, ...].astype(np.float32)

    images_data = []
    for i in range(1):
        images_data.append(image_data)
    images_data = np.asarray(images_data).astype(np.float32)

    if FLAGS.framework == 'tflite':
        interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=FLAGS.weights)
        interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
        output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
        print(input_details)
        print(output_details)
        interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], images_data)
        interpreter.invoke()
        pred = [interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[i]['index']) for i in range(len(output_details))]
        if FLAGS.model == 'yolov3' and FLAGS.tiny == True:
            boxes, pred_conf = filter_boxes(pred[1], pred[0], score_threshold=0.25, input_shape=tf.constant([input_size, input_size]))
        else:
            boxes, pred_conf = filter_boxes(pred[0], pred[1], score_threshold=0.25, input_shape=tf.constant([input_size, input_size]))
    else:
        saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(FLAGS.weights, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
        infer = saved_model_loaded.signatures['serving_default']
        batch_data = tf.constant(images_data)
        pred_bbox = infer(batch_data)
        for key, value in pred_bbox.items():
            boxes = value[:, :, 0:4]
            pred_conf = value[:, :, 4:]

    boxes, scores, classes, valid_detections = tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression(
        boxes=tf.reshape(boxes, (tf.shape(boxes)[0], -1, 1, 4)),
        scores=tf.reshape(
            pred_conf, (tf.shape(pred_conf)[0], -1, tf.shape(pred_conf)[-1])),
        max_output_size_per_class=50,
        max_total_size=50,
        iou_threshold=FLAGS.iou,
        score_threshold=FLAGS.score
    )
    final_boxes = boxes.numpy()
    final_scores = scores.numpy()
    final_classes = classes.numpy()

    array_boxes_detected = get_human_box_detection(final_boxes,final_scores[0].tolist(),final_classes[0].tolist(),original_image.shape[0],original_image.shape[1])
    print(array_boxes_detected)
    
    #Defining red color rgb value
    COLOR_RED = (0, 0, 255)
    for i,items in enumerate(array_boxes_detected):
        first_point = array_boxes_detected[i][0]
        second_point = array_boxes_detected[i][1]
        third_point = array_boxes_detected[i][2]
        fourth_point = array_boxes_detected[i][3]
        cv2.rectangle(original_image,(second_point,first_point),(fourth_point,third_point),COLOR_RED,2)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(original_image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow("final", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(main)
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

I am in learning phase for `deep learning`, `tensorflow` and `flask`. So, any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. I have tested using postman.

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
from absl import app, flags, logging
from absl.flags import FLAGS
import core.utils as utils
from core.yolov4 import filter_boxes
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from PIL import Image
import os
import sys
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
from helping_functions import get_centroids, get_human_box_detection, get_points_from_box
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify, send_from_directory, abort

flags.DEFINE_string('framework', 'tf', '(tf, tflite, trt')
flags.DEFINE_string('weights', './checkpoints/yolov4-416',
                    'path to weights file')
flags.DEFINE_integer('size', 320, 'resize images to')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('tiny', False, 'yolo or yolo-tiny')
flags.DEFINE_string('model', 'yolov4', 'yolov3 or yolov4')
flags.DEFINE_string('image', './data/kite.jpg', 'path to input image')
flags.DEFINE_string('output', 'result.png', 'path to output image')
flags.DEFINE_float('iou', 0.45, 'iou threshold')
flags.DEFINE_float('score', 0.25, 'score threshold')
FLAGS(sys.argv)

# Initialize Flask application
flask_app = Flask(__name__)

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
STRIDES, ANCHORS, NUM_CLASS, XYSCALE = utils.load_config(FLAGS)
saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(FLAGS.weights, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
infer = saved_model_loaded.signatures['serving_default']
input_size = FLAGS.size

# API that returns JSON with classes found in images
@flask_app.route('/detection', methods=['POST'])
def human_detect():
    image = request.files["images"]
    image_path = image.filename
    image.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_path))
    if image_path != "":
        original_image = cv2.imread(f"./{image_path}")
        original_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        image_data = cv2.resize(original_image, (input_size, input_size))
        image_data = image_data / 255.
        image_data = image_data[np.newaxis, ...].astype(np.float32)
        batch_data = tf.constant(image_data)
        pred_bbox = infer(batch_data)

        for key, value in pred_bbox.items():
            boxes = value[:, :, 0:4]
            pred_conf = value[:, :, 4:]

        boxes, scores, classes, valid_detections = tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression(
            boxes=tf.reshape(boxes, (tf.shape(boxes)[0], -1, 1, 4)),
            scores=tf.reshape(
                pred_conf, (tf.shape(pred_conf)[0], -1, tf.shape(pred_conf)[-1])),
            max_output_size_per_class=50,
            max_total_size=50,
            iou_threshold=FLAGS.iou,
            score_threshold=FLAGS.score
        )
        final_boxes = boxes.numpy()
        final_scores = scores.numpy()
        final_classes = classes.numpy()
        array_boxes_detected = []
        if len(boxes)>0:
            array_boxes_detected = get_human_box_detection(final_boxes,final_scores[0].tolist(),final_classes[0].tolist(),original_image.shape[0],original_image.shape[1])
        try:
            return jsonify({"response":array_boxes_detected}), 200
        except FileNotFoundError:
            abort(404)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run(debug=True, host = '127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

Comment: can you share the complete project link ,it'll help me in understanding it.